# Scala: for-comprehension to turn String into Map[Char, Int]

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, for-comprehension

What would be a good method to loop through a String in Scala with a for-comprehension and yield a map of characters and an integer representing how many times that character is in the string?

```
def mapString(s: String): Map[Char, Int] = {
     for(c<-s) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mapString(s: String): Map[Char, Int] = {
    s.groupBy(c => c).map{case(c,str) => c-> str.size}.toMap
  }
```